# Intellij - Add project as dependency to another project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to make my project work on intellij (it works with eclipse). I have a project with this in my pom:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.fitnetapplication</groupId>
  <artifactId>fitnet-common</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.2-Final</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>FitnetCommon</name>
  <description>Socle Commun FitnetManager / SyrhaLogic</description>
```

Now i have another project which needs to be linked to this one, so I had:
     
        
            com.fitnetapplication
            fitnet-common
            6.0.2-Final
            runtime
            war

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fitnetapplication</groupId>
        <artifactId>fitnet-common</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is that on Intellij, the version is not accepted for some reason, I don't know why, it tells me that the version 6.0.2-Final is not found for the artifact fitnet-common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm - you are actually running `mvn clean install` (or similar) on the first project before trying to resolve the dependency in the second project?

If you are, it sounds like you're installing the project using one Maven repo location, and then in the other project it is looking in a completely different location. Are your .m2 location settings identical for both projects?

**Edit:**

Is it because you're specifying the first project as a `war` packaging, but in the dependency declaration you are looking for a `jar`? They would essentially be two different artefacts:

1. .war - `com.fitnetapplication:fitnet-common:6.0.2-Final:war`
2. .jar - `com.fitnetapplication:fitnet-common:6.0.2-Final:jar`

Check in your `.m2/com/fitnetapplication/fitnet-common/6.0.2-Final` to see what you have there, likely it is just the `war` file.

Comment: Yes I did run mvn clean install on the 'common project'. And I just checked, both maven repo locations are the same in both projects. I do not have any error on the groupid or artefact id, however the version is red and it says "dependency not found".  As you can see in my first post, the versions are the same :(

Comment: Hmmm you specify war in one and jar in the dependency. This could be the issue. I have updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Actually the maven clean wasn't enough, I launched every step of the lifecycle and it did the job ! Thanks !